# Считывание из файла в список (коллекцию)

Tags: java, файлы, коллекции

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно считывать из файла в данный список.

```
List <Data> list = new LinkedList <Data>();

public class Data{
  private static String name;
  private static Double age;
}
```

Файл

```
  john 25
  inna 23
```

Comment: Какая ожидается структура файла? И зачем у полей `name` и `age` модификатор `static`?

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
 try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        int index = line.lastIndexOf(' ');
        if (index == -1) {
            // Wrong format
        } else {
            String name = line.substring(0, index);
            Double age = 0.0; // dafault value
            try {
                age = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(index));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Wrong format
            }
            list.add(new Data(name, age));
        }
    }
    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

P.S. Использование `LinkedList` вместо `ArrayList` актуально только тогда, когда часто производятся операции вставки и удаления элементов.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбирать.

Comment: Одно маленькое дополнение, если у нас Data имеет 2 и больше полей String, файл изменяется в соответствии, то как будет выглядеть запись

Comment: Либо методом `String.split`, либо самому написать регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной задачи можно использовать `Streams`, например, следующим образом:

```
List<Data> dataList = Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file"))
        .filter(s -> s.contains(" "))
        .map(s -> s.split(" "))
        .map(ss -> new Data(
                Arrays.stream(ss)
                        .limit(ss.length - 1)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")),
                Double.parseDouble(ss[ss.length - 1])))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Если имена в исходном файле не могут содержать пробелы (т.е. в каждой строке пробел используется только в качестве разделителя) - можно упростить:

```
List<Data> dataList = Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file"))
        .filter(s -> s.contains(" "))
        .map(s -> s.split(" "))
        .map(ss -> new Data(ss[0], Double.parseDouble(ss[1])))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```